# R crashes when using tidyr::unnest_wider

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, unnest

Running `tidyr::unnest_wider` as part of a pipe, e.g.

```
df <- df %>%
unnest_wider(col, names_sep = "_", names_repair = "universal")
```

R crashes with the following error reported,

```
[91205:91206:20220410,071753.955164:ERROR file_io_posix.cc:148] open /home/matt/.r/crashpad_database/pending/dc2183c4-0851-4c62-908e-7d4e41a2702e.lock: File exists (17)
[91205:91205:20220410,071753.957703:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:86] read out of range
[91205:91205:20220410,071753.957712:ERROR elf_image_reader.cc:558] missing nul-terminator
[91205:91205:20220410,071753.957794:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[91205:91205:20220410,071753.960132:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[91205:91205:20220410,071753.960189:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[91205:91205:20220410,071753.960236:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
[91205:91205:20220410,071753.960281:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found
```

The data frame I'm working with is quite complex with many columns, several of which are nested. Here's the structure of the column I'm trying to unnest (showing only the first 3 elements as the other 1453 are similar):

```
> str(spatial_firing$shuffle_results_b_o)
List of 1456
 $ : tibble [1,000 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ neuron   : int [1:1000] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  ..$ r.squared: num [1:1000] 0.004358 0.036137 0.015214 0.001598 0.000695 ...
  ..$ slope    : num [1:1000] 0.01191 0.02476 0.02087 -0.00629 -0.00461 ...
  ..$ p.value  : num [1:1000] 0.616 0.146 0.348 0.762 0.842 ...
 $ : tibble [1,000 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ neuron   : int [1:1000] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  ..$ r.squared: num [1:1000] 0.00722 0.01216 0.00534 0.01284 0.04958 ...
  ..$ slope    : num [1:1000] 0.0203 -0.0223 -0.0157 0.0209 -0.0448 ...
  ..$ p.value  : num [1:1000] 0.5186 0.4015 0.5791 0.3886 0.0873 ...
 $ : tibble [1,000 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ neuron   : int [1:1000] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  ..$ r.squared: num [1:1000] 0.000795 0.001298 0.00132 0.000165 0.033603 ...
  ..$ slope    : num [1:1000] -0.00453 0.00685 0.00645 -0.0024 0.04619 ...
  ..$ p.value  : num [1:1000] 0.831 0.785 0.783 0.922 0.161 ...
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
f <- function(n) {
  df <- tibble(neuron=0:(n-1), r.squared = rnorm(n),
                        slope = rnorm(n), p.value = rnorm(n))
  df$p.value[2] <- NA
  df
}
df <- replicate(1000, f(1000), simplify = FALSE)

dff <- tibble(x=df)
for (i in 1:100) { 
  cat(i, "\n")
  unnest_wider(dff, x)
}
```

On my machine introducing the NAs causes this to crash typically at step 3 or 4. In the answer below the code will crash without the NAs but this doesn't happen reliably on my machine.

Things I've tried include:

- Simplifying as much as possible the data frame I'm working with. This hasn't helped.
- Inspecting memory usage. This doesn't seem to be an issue. There's plenty of free RAM, and my simple example code runs fine when I fill up the RAM and most of the swap space.
- Running the code on the same machine in a Rocker image. This replicates the crash.
- Running the code in emacs/ESS rather than R Studio. The code fails at the same point.

I'm running R version 4.1.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.4.

I'd welcome suggestions for solutions or additional trouble shooting tests.

Comment: Try with `unnest` as you may different number of rows in the original data and the nested tibble i.e. `spatial_firing %>% unnest(shuffle_results_b_o)`

Comment: Using a reproducible example `df <- tibble(col1 = 1:3, shuffle_results_b_o = list(tibble(neuron = 1:5, r.squared = 6:10, slope = 1:5), tibble(neuron = 11:15, r.squared = 16:20), tibble(neuron = 11:15, r.squared = 16:20)));df %>% unnest(shuffle_results_b_o)` works fine with `unnest`

Comment: Very much like to see this as an answer, with a little discussion of taking an `str` and coaxing it to `dput`, as it seems you've done, or I misinterpret, very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed by updating r-lib/vctrs with:

```
devtools::install_github("r-lib/vctrs#1553")
```

I've confirmed that this works with the reproducible example and with the original issue.

Update:
The fixed r-lib/vctrs is now available from CRAN.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but a reproducible example. Seems like a bug in `tidyr` or somewhere in the underlying tidyverse machinery (a segmentation fault is by definition a bug - nothing an R end-user does that doesn't mess around with compiled (C++/Fortran/etc.) code should ever be able to crash the R session, except possibly due to memory exhaustion).

I would post a [tidyr issue about this](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues) if I were you ... (it also happens with the latest development version of `tidyr`).

```r
library(tidyverse)
f <- function(n) tibble(neuron=0:(n-1), r.squared = rnorm(n),
     slope = rnorm(n), p.value = rnorm(n))
df <- replicate(1000, f(1000), simplify = FALSE)
```

Results look like yours:

```r
str(df[1:3])
List of 3
 $ : tibble [1,000 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ neuron   : int [1:1000] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  ..$ r.squared: num [1:1000] 0.421 -0.445 0.816 0.752 0.635 ...
  ..$ slope    : num [1:1000] 0.059 -1.4899 -0.0384 0.2601 -0.6293 ...
  ..$ p.value  : num [1:1000] -0.754 1.023 0.123 0.817 0.382 ...
 $ : tibble [1,000 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ neuron   : int [1:1000] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  ..$ r.squared: num [1:1000] 0.504 0.153 -1.397 0.938 0.948 ...
  ..$ slope    : num [1:1000] 0.9693 -1.2223 -0.4863 1.0936 -0.0792 ...
  ..$ p.value  : num [1:1000] -1.018 -2.313 -1.593 -0.528 0.783 ...
 $ : tibble [1,000 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ neuron   : int [1:1000] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
  ..$ r.squared: num [1:1000] 0.73 -0.926 2.144 0.795 1.002 ...
  ..$ slope    : num [1:1000] -1.622 -0.664 1.286 0.419 1.285 ...
  ..$ p.value  : num [1:1000] 1.408 -1.458 -1.096 0.339 -0.295 ...
```

`unnest_wider` is supposed to be applied to a list-column and you're showing us a list, so I'll make a list-column out of it.

This crashes on iteration 3 on my machine (segmentation fault with "memory not mapped").

```r
dff <- tibble(x=df)
for (i in 1:100) { 
   cat(i, "\n")
   unnest_wider(dff, x)
}
```

---

R unstable, PopOS! 21.04, tidyr version 1.2.0

Comment: In a new terminal starting [htop] at 3.49G, I'm at cat(i, "\n") `42` and 3.52G...and no crash so far, but perhaps that's `42`.

Comment: Competes at i/100, 3.49G, highest reached, 3.55G. dff$x[100][[1]][1,]
`# A tibble: 1 × 4
  neuron r.squared slope p.value
   <int>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1      0     0.872 0.535    1.80`. And...I guess it's not `42`.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I've posted an [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/1348) and will update here if there's a fix.

Comment: When I include NAs in the list column data frame in the example above it reliably fails. I've updated the question to include this as a reproducible example. It would be great to know if this fails on other machines.